# Why is NTFS so much slower on Windows than Linux (Debian)

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ntfs

I use an external USB drive for most of my personal data. It's formatted as NTFS because I use it both at home on my Debian PC, and on my school computers, which run Windows 10. I've recently been writing a program that creates hundereds of small (< 5kb) files on the drive, and have found that it executes in about 1.5 seconds on Debian, but takes well over 20 on Windows. What I find even more suprising is that the Debian machine was connected via USB 2.0, while the Windows machine was conencted over USB 3.0 (yes, the drive does support 3.0). What's the reason for this? I'd expect the Debian support to be much slower, as all the drivers are unofficial and reverse-engineered while Windows' are official.

Comment: (1) Programs (their ports) in different OS-es may execute slower or faster even if they don't create files. (2). In Debian, did you use `sync` afterwards?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. It's just a simple Java program that uses file ouput streams to write plain UTF-8 text to files (https://github.com/PorkLib/primitive/blob/master/generator/src/main/java/net/daporkchop/lib/collection/generator/impl/MapGenerator.java#L44-L49)

Comment: What is the file format of those small files?

Comment: Shouldn't really matter, it's just plain UTF-8 text. They're all .java files.

Comment: At 5 kB a file USB 2 vs USB 3 would perform identically.  So the differences are unrelated to the USB mode

Comment: If you don't `sync`, then the files will probably still be in the filesystem cache... Try doing the operation, and immediately following it with a call to `sync` - time the whole thing.

Comment: Windows defaults to not write caching external drives.  Set it to enable write caching.